# Add existing files to visual studio project

Tags: visual-studio

I have a straightorward console application that I build using code::blocks.  A client has requested a microsoft visual studio project to build it.  So I downloaded and installed visual studio and created a project.  Now I am trying to add my source files to the project.

Various online help pages say "Select project; select menu item "Add Existing Item" ( e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100).  I cannot find "add existing item"!  Add new item simply adds an empty file.

[image]

I tried dragging files from windows explorer onto the project, but this REMOVES the file from where it belongs - NOT what I want to happen.

Surely there must be a way to do this!  Even without using alternative IDEs, different projects frequently must share common source code, so source files from one project need to be added to another.

Comment: Move the files into a folder for your project. Click the "Show All Files" button at top of Solution Explorer. Select the files, right click to choose "Include in Project". https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/05/21/visual-studio-tip-8-adding-existing-files-with-show-all-files/

Comment: @SteveGreene I certainly do not want to move the files around.  I want them to remain exactly where they are, so that my current build is not broken.  The idea is that I can build using codeblocks and the client can build using MSVC, both of us using the same files.  Also, the files in the project are in several different folders.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use `File | New | Project from Existing code` rather than simple '`New Project`' when creating the project